# Converting from Riemann sum to definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Can someone please explain how to convert this into a definite integral in the form 
$ \int_a^b f(x)dx $
And please explain how you get `a` and `b` and the rest.

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow  \infty } \bigg( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{a-1}{n}   \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}   \frac{1}{(1+ \frac{k}{n}(a-1))^{2}} \bigg)$$
One question: I understand that this:
$$\lim_{a \rightarrow  \infty } \bigg( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n}   \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}   \frac{1}{(1+ \frac{k}{n})^{2}} \bigg) = \frac{1}{x^2}$$
What happens to the $$\frac{a-1}{n}$$ and $${(a-1)}$$
When:
$$\lim_{a \rightarrow  \infty } \bigg( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{a-1}{n}   \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}   \frac{1}{(1+ \frac{k}{n}(a-1))^{2}} \bigg) = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx  $$

Answer (score 1):

The point is to guess. First of all, forget about the limit $a\to \infty$. When you want to approximate $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ by sums of area of rectangles, you divide the intervals $[a, b]$ into $n$ equals parts with width $\frac{b-a}{n}$. Thus one would guess the integral would be something like

$$\int_{1+ c}^{a+c} f(x) dx$$

for some unknown $c$. Now for $f$, we put in $k=0$ to see that the summation term is

$$\frac{1}{(1)^2},$$

and put in $k=n-1$ we have

$$\frac{1}{(1+ \frac{n-1}{n}(a-1))^2}\sim \frac{1}{(1+ (a-1))^2} = \frac{1}{(a)^2} .$$

when $n$ is very big. Thus one good guess would be

$$\int_1^a \frac{1}{x^2} dx\ .$$

Now you take care of the limit $a\to \infty$ to see that it should be

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow  \infty } \bigg( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{a-1}{n}   \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}   \frac{1}{(1+ \frac{k}{n}(a-1))^{2}} \bigg) = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx = -\frac{1}{x}\bigg|_1^\infty = 1$$

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much! But I have one question.Why isn't this correct for the third step: $$\frac{1}{(1+ \frac{n-1}{n}(a-1))^2}\sim \frac{1}{(2+ (a-1))^2} = \frac{1}{(a+1)^2} $$? @John

Comment: @Andy: When $n$ is big, $\frac{n-1}{n} \sim 1$, so it should be $1/a^2$.

Comment: you're right, when n is big, $$\frac{n-1}{n} \sim 1$$ but what about the other 1 that is$$ 1 + \frac{n-1}{n}$$? And since $$\frac{n-1}{n} \sim 1 $$, $$1+\frac{n-1}{n} = 2$$ Right? By the way sorry if my questions annoy you. I am just a bit confused.

Comment: @Andy: In your equation I do not know why there is a $2$. It should be 
$$\frac{1}{(1+ \frac{n-1}{n}(a-1))^2}\sim\frac{1}{(1 + (a-1))^2} = \frac{1}{a^2}$$

Comment: @Andy The $\frac{n-1}{n}$ is being multiplied to $a-1$ first and then you add 1.

Comment: @mathematician Ohhhhh, I seeeeeeeeeeee.Silly me!!!